# Will Angular SwPush & web-push work when the browser is closed

Tags: service-worker, web-push

I followed this tutorial to create push notifications through an Angular app & nodejs service:
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-push-notifications

My question is, will these notifications come up when the browser is closed? Or, will they come up on mobile when the mobile browser is closed?

Because, I am looking for a way to create mobile push notifications (the same type of push notifications that app's use) but from the Angular app. The goal of course it to be able to send the user push notifications while the user isn't on the Angular web app. Stuff like "Hey! A new booking has been made. Go check out your online profile quickly!"

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I did, and it is not working. But I don't know if I am doing something wrong or trying something impossible

Comment: It's working OK when the browser is open (after you said Allow to notifications)?

Comment: After you said Allow to notifications, you see your service worker installed properly? Dev Tools > Application > Service Workers

Comment: I am also interested in knowing wether this notifications will work on mobile as well or if they work on desktop only. @PaulKruger did you find out?

Comment: Yes it did work hey :) I had a problem on my side

Comment: could you share your working example, i have same problem

Comment: It is exactly the tutorial I linked above. But you have to serve this over `httpS`, normal `http` won't work

Comment: So @PaulKruger, will it work on localhost?
Because I tried I didnt get any notifications in localhost